# Archimedean Property equivalence to Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I have to prove that 
Given: $y>0$, there exists an $n$ in the natural numbers such that $\frac{1}{n}<y$.

Prove: $x>0$, there exists an $n$ in the natural numbers such that $n>x$.

These are both theorems that are equivalent to the Archimedean property.

So far I have:

Let $x>0$. Then $\frac{1}{n}<x$.

I'm not sure if that's the right direction to go in or what comes next.

Comment: Something is missing here. You write: Given: $y>0$, there exists an $n$ in the natural numbers such that $1/n$ – but there is no mention of $y$. I also assume that $y$ is universally quantified. A similar remark holds for the statement that you have to prove.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just forgot that part. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y = 1/x$; we now know by assumption that there exists an $n$ such that $1/n < y$. But this then means that $1/y < n$. Since $1/y = x$, we therefore have that there exists an $n$ such $n > x$.